# I'm making a psuedo-hyperwebster in python, and I keep having the issue where the code will give me less than 100% of the strings I should be getting

Tags: python, python-3.x

The pseudo-hyperwebster *should* have exactly 17567 resulting strings after running on three characters. However, it only gives me 92% of the results I should be getting at 16300 strings.

This is the code I used:

```py
abcs = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", \
"h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", \
"q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
entrydict = {}

#Variables
ites = 0
char1 = 0
char2 = 0
char3 = 0
char4 = 0
char5 = 0
char6 = 0
char7 = 0
char8 = 0
char9 = 0
char10 = 0
char11 = 0
char12 = 0
char13 = 0
char14 = 0
char15 = 0
word_guess = ""

################################################################################

#Actual Cracker
word_guess = abcs[char1] + abcs[char2] + abcs[char3] + abcs[char4] \
    + abcs[char5] + abcs[char6] + abcs[char7] + abcs[char8] + abcs[char9] \
    + abcs[char10] + abcs[char11] + abcs[char12] + abcs[char13] + abcs[char14] \
    + abcs[char15]
while True:
    if char15 < 25:
        char15 += 1
    elif char14 < 25:
        char14 += 1
        char15 -= 25
    elif char13 < 25:
        char13 += 1
        char14 -= 25
    elif char12 < 25:
        char12 += 1
        char13 -= 25
    elif char11 < 25:
        char11 += 1
        char12 -= 25
    elif char10 < 25:
        char10 += 1
        char11 -= 25
    elif char9 < 25:
        char9 += 1
        char10 -= 25
    elif char8 < 25:
        char8 += 1
        char9 -= 25
    elif char7 < 25:
        char7 += 1
        char8 -= 25
    elif char6 < 25:
        char6 += 1
        char7 -= 25
    elif char5 < 25:
        char5 += 1
        char6 -= 25
    elif char4 < 25:
        char4 += 1
        char5 -= 25
    elif char3 < 25:
        char3 += 1
        char4 -= 25
    elif char2 < 25:
        char2 += 1
        char3 -= 25
    elif char1 < 25:
        char1 += 1
        char2 -= 25
    word_guess = abcs[char1] + abcs[char2] + abcs[char3] + abcs[char4] \
        + abcs[char5] + abcs[char6] + abcs[char7] + abcs[char8] + abcs[char9] \
        + abcs[char10] + abcs[char11] + abcs[char12] + abcs[char13] + abcs[char14] \
        + abcs[char15]
    ites += 1
    if ites < 1000000:
        entrydict[ites] = word_guess
    if char13 == 25:
        break

################################################################################

print(f'There were {str(ites)} iterations recognized.')
while True:
    try:
        index = int(input("Give an index: "))
        print(f'Index {index} contains: {entrydict[index]}')
    except IndexError:
        print("Whoops!, IndexError")
        continue
    except TypeError:
        print("Whoops!, TypeError")
        continue
    except ValueError:
        print("Whoops!, ValueError")
        continue
    except KeyError:
        print("Whoops!, KeyError")
        continue
```

I tried modifying the numbers to make it generate everything, although it may be a limitation of the hardware I am using. I also went through and troubleshot all the variables and equations. I expected it to change, but nothing was different.

Comment: If you want all 26 things to be used, then everywhere you have `25` you should actually have `26`.  There are many, many, many better ways to do this, although the task is pointless.  You realize that, even if you do a million entries a second, it will take 5 million years to go through all the combinations?

Comment: And your "carry" strategy is flawed.  Have you printed your strings?  You go "jzy", "jzz", "kaz", "kba".  A carry has to propagate through many columns, not just one.

Comment: What's more, you don't actually need to "store" all of the entries.  If you want to know the string at index 12345, you just have to convert that to a number in base 26.

Comment: My problem lies not with computing time or anything like that. I just want it to generate all 17657 strings and not 16300. The problem is also not in how the list is called. Because it is python, the list starts at index 0, so it iterates through the list just fine when 25 is used. Something else is screwy and I want to know how to fix the other thing.

Comment: Look what happens when the last three are "5 25 25".  char15 is not < 25, so you skip the first clause.  char14 is not < 25, so you skip the second clause.  Now char13 is < 25, so you bump char 13 and set char14 to 0.  Now you have "6 0 25".  Do you see the problem?  If you bump char13, you need to reset ALL the lower digits.  If you had "5 25 25 25", you would produce "6 0 25 25".  THAT'S where your miscount comes from.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list of all 3-letter combinations of lower-case letters, there's no need to complicate things. (I assume, like Tim said in the comments, that you have an off-by-one error in your original code.)

```
import string

abcs = string.ascii_lowercase

entries = []

for ch1 in abcs:
    for ch2 in abcs:
        for ch3 in abcs:
            entries.append(ch1 + ch2 + ch3)

print(len(entries))
```

This happily prints out 17576 (26 ** 3).

This can be further simplified as

```
import itertools
import string

entries = list(itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=3))
print(len(entries))
```

if you like, which also allows you to increase the `N` by just changing that `3` to something else.

Comment: I made the program to print through all the iterations of an arbitrarily large string and save them to a dictionary.

Comment: This does essentially the very same thing.